# Unity 2D 'Attack()' is a local function and must therefore always have a body

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a function named "Attack()" that will ocurr diferently if the player is facing a diferent direction in Unity 2D but i am getting the error that i have stated above. I am also getting this error "'Attack' does not exist in the current context" . I am fairly new to Unity so please have patience. Here is the code

` public class PlayerCombat : MonoBehaviour {

```
public Transform AttackAreaRight;
public float AttackRangeRight = 0.5f;
public float AttackRangeLeft = 0.5f;
public Transform AttackAreaLeft;
public bool IsFacingRight = true;
public bool IsFacingLeft = false;
public LayerMask EnemyLayers;
void Update()
{
    
   if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        IsFacingRight = false;
        IsFacingLeft = true;
        Debug.Log("FacingLeft");
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        IsFacingLeft = false;
        IsFacingRight = true;
        Debug.Log("FacingRight");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        Attack();
    }
    if (IsFacingRight = true) ;
    {
        void Attack()
        {
            Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackAreaRight.position, AttackRangeRight, EnemyLayers);
            foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
            {
                Debug.Log("LMAORight");
            }
        }
    }
    if (IsFacingLeft = true) ;
    {
        void Attack();
        {
            Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackAreaLeft.position, AttackRangeLeft, EnemyLayers);
            foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
            {
                Debug.Log("LMAOLeft");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}
`

Comment: well you declared "attack" inside an if statement (jn fact 2 of them)  and if you press F what exactly did you expect attack to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's a few issues here. This is more what you want.

```
public Transform AttackAreaRight;
public float AttackRangeRight = 0.5f;
public float AttackRangeLeft = 0.5f;
public Transform AttackAreaLeft;
public bool IsFacingRight = true;
public LayerMask EnemyLayers;
void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        IsFacingRight = false;
        Debug.Log("FacingLeft");
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        IsFacingRight = false;
        Debug.Log("FacingRight");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
    {
        Attack();
    }
}

void Attack()
{
    Vector2 attackPosition;
    float attackRange;
    if (IsFacingRight)
    {
        attackPosition = AttackAreaRight.position;
        attackRange = AttackRangeRight;
    }
    else 
    {
        attackPosition = AttackAreaLeft.position;
        attackRange = AttackRangeLeft;
    }
    Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPosition, attackRange, EnemyLayers);

    foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
    {
        Debug.Log("Attacked");
    }
}
```

So the first problem is you declared a function inside a function. Update() is a unity function called every frame so inside of it you can't have a function declared (that what you were doing with void Attack()).

Now if you want to set a value for your character's direction (left/right) its easier to only have 1 boolean so you don't have errors later on like IsLeft bieng true and IsRight being true. Since if IsRight is true than IsLeft must be false and so on.

You can then check this boolean inside the attack function and set the corresponding data for the OverlapCircle.

Comment: You can declare functions inside functions they are called local functions its a C#7 feature

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it is working or not but at least now not giving error on compilation.
If you could test it.

```
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerCombat : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform AttackAreaRight;
public float AttackRangeRight = 0.5f;
public float AttackRangeLeft = 0.5f;
public Transform AttackAreaLeft;
public bool IsFacingRight = true;
public bool IsFacingLeft = false;
public LayerMask EnemyLayers;
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
    {
        IsFacingRight = false;
        IsFacingLeft = true;
        Debug.Log("FacingLeft");
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.D))
    {
        IsFacingLeft = false;
        IsFacingRight = true;
        Debug.Log("FacingRight");
    }
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F)){
        Attack();
    }
}
 private void Attack()
 {
        if (IsFacingLeft == true && IsFacingRight == false)
        {

            Collider2D[] hitEnemies = 
Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackAreaLeft.position, AttackRangeLeft, EnemyLayers);
            foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
                {
                Debug.Log("LMAOLeft");
                }
        }

        else if (IsFacingRight == true  && IsFacingLeft == false)
        {
            Collider2D[] hitEnemies = 
Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(AttackAreaRight.position, AttackRangeRight, EnemyLayers);
            foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
                {
                Debug.Log("LMAORight");
                }
        }
    }
}
```